# Adding columns in Pandas from a dataframe using melt, merge or join

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to combine columns in pandas similar to the following, but I'm not sure whether to use merge, melt, concat.

| column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| table |  | table |
| cat |  | cat |
| dog | dog | dog |
| chair |  | chair |
|  | car | car |
|  | barbell | barbell |

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a new column with all values of `column1`, and then fill missing values with `column2`. To do so, use [`fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html). You have to think about which value has "priority" over the other (which column do you use first).

Here, it will be `column1`.

```
df['column3'] = df['column1'].fillna(df['column2'])
```